# Can scala.util.Random.nextInt (): Int occasionally return a negative value?

Tags: scala, random

Documentation for `scala.util.Random.nextInt (n: Int): Int` says "Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)..." while for `scala.util.Random.nextInt (): Int` it says "Returns the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value...", without saying anything about the zero. Can I get a negative value here occasionally?

Comment: Where does it say that?  The docs I found said "All 2^32 possible int values are produced with (approximately) equal probability", which means that negative numbers are *more* likely than positive ones (since there is one more negative number).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently, yes. It returned a negative value on my first try! :-)

```
scala> import util.Random
import util.Random

scala> Random.nextInt
res0: Int = -299006430
```

Comment: what are the odds of that?! :)

Comment: @FabienWarniez, what are the odds of you commenting this on my ancient post yesterday, and me running into similar situation at about the same time? :) https://twitter.com/missingfaktor/status/914642815854006272

Comment: I am a little bit spooked TBH!

Comment: This answer from 2011 was the second search result when I looked for `scala random int non-zero`. Maybe it's a sign.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can (and that's ok due to [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29) of uniform distribution). Moreover you'll get it in nearly 50% of cases.

```
(for(i <- 1 to 100000) yield scala.util.Random.nextInt()).filter(_<0).length
```

have yielded for me 49946 - that's quite close to the 50%.

Comment: On average, in fact, *exactly* 50% of cases

Comment: @Luigi Don't forget about neutral cases, when random value is equals to 0. So there is would be 49,9...% percents of positive, the same number of negatives and a few of zeros.

Comment: I didn't forget... well, I'm assuming any value is equally likely. Maybe you can't get Int.MinValue or something. There are 2147483648 negative, 2147483647 positive, and 1 zero Int

Answer (score 10):

As you can see [here](http://harrah.github.com/browse/samples/library/scala/util/Random.scala.html) (using Mike Harrah's excellent **sxr**), Scala's `Random` just delegates to an underlying `java.util.Random`, which is referred to as `self`.

As others pointed out the default range is between `Integer.MIN_VAL` and `Integer.MAX_VAL`, in other words, any `Integer` possible, including the negative ones.

If you want just the positive range, you can use the overloaded method `nextInt` that takes an argument, like this:

```
Random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

According to the docs:

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0
>   (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this
>   random number generator's sequence.

Comment: If you want the positive range, you'd rather do: `Random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE+1)`, since 0 is not considered positive and Integer.MAX_VALUE is going to be excluded at the top end.

Answer (score 2):

scala.uti.Random.nextInt (): Int leverages the same method of java.util.Random. And the range as Luigi pointed out is [Integer.MIN_VAL,Integer.MAX_VAL]. Actually "uniformly distributed int value" means any number of int type is possible to be returned and the chance of each one in theory to be the same.